# InvalidArgumentException: The file "/var/www/html/secerp/app/config/config_.yml" does not exist

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.5

I have the problem that after the installation of FOSUserBundle I cannot access to Symfony anymore. Every command returns

```
[InvalidArgumentException]  The file "/var/www/html/secerp/app/config/config_.yml" does not exist.
```

Seems he lost the this->environment Infomation of the app/AppKernel

```
public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
```

Changes I did before:

```
[root@symfony secerp]# composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0@dev"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets
Trying to install assets as symbolic links.
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodistribution
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget
[root@symfony secerp]# cd vendor/
autoload.php      doctrine/         incenteev/        kriswallsmith/    psr/              sensiolabs/       symfony/
composer/         friendsofsymfony/ jdorn/            monolog/          sensio/           swiftmailer/      twig/
[root@symfony secerp]# cd vendor/
autoload.php      doctrine/         incenteev/        kriswallsmith/    psr/              sensiolabs/       symfony/
composer/         friendsofsymfony/ jdorn/            monolog/          sensio/           swiftmailer/      twig/
[root@symfony secerp]# php app/console cache:clear --env=prod


  [InvalidArgumentException]
  The file "/var/www/html/secerp/app/config/config_.yml" does not exist.
```

Can somebody help me to fix this problem or had the same problem before?

EDIT: Running the composer update again leads to the following results:

```
[root@symfony secerp]# composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache



  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException]
  A string value must be composed of strings and/or numbers, but found parameter "kernel.environment" of type NULL inside string value "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log".



Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.



update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

With the following error when I access a page:

```
RuntimeException in ParameterBag.php line 251:
A string value must be composed of strings and/or numbers, but found parameter "kernel.environment" of type NULL inside string value "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log".
in ParameterBag.php line 251
at ParameterBag->Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\{closure}(array('%kernel.environment%', 'kernel.environment'))
at preg_replace_callback('/%%|%([^%\s]+)%/', object(Closure), '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log') in ParameterBag.php line 258
at ParameterBag->resolveString('%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log', array()) in ParameterBag.php line 203
at ParameterBag->resolveValue('%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log', array()) in ParameterBag.php line 193
at ParameterBag->resolveValue(array('type' => 'stream', 'path' => '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log', 'level' => 'debug'), array()) in ParameterBag.php line 193
at ParameterBag->resolveValue(array('main' => array('type' => 'stream', 'path' => '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log', 'level' => 'debug'), 'console' => array('type' => 'console', 'bubble' => false, 'verbosity_levels' => array('VERBOSITY_VERBOSE' => 'INFO', 'VERBOSITY_VERY_VERBOSE' => 'DEBUG'), 'channels' => array('!doctrine')), 'console_very_verbose' => array('type' => 'console', 'bubble' => false, 'verbosity_levels' => array('VERBOSITY_VERBOSE' => 'NOTICE', 'VERBOSITY_VERY_VERBOSE' => 'NOTICE', 'VERBOSITY_DEBUG' => 'DEBUG'), 'channels' => array('doctrine'))), array()) in ParameterBag.php line 193
at ParameterBag->resolveValue(array('handlers' => array('main' => array('type' => 'stream', 'path' => '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log', 'level' => 'debug'), 'console' => array('type' => 'console', 'bubble' => false, 'verbosity_levels' => array('VERBOSITY_VERBOSE' => 'INFO', 'VERBOSITY_VERY_VERBOSE' => 'DEBUG'), 'channels' => array('!doctrine')), 'console_very_verbose' => array('type' => 'console', 'bubble' => false, 'verbosity_levels' => array('VERBOSITY_VERBOSE' => 'NOTICE', 'VERBOSITY_VERY_VERBOSE' => 'NOTICE', 'VERBOSITY_DEBUG' => 'DEBUG'), 'channels' => array('doctrine')))), array()) in ParameterBag.php line 193
at ParameterBag->resolveValue(array(array('handlers' => array('main' => array('type' => 'stream', 'path' => '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log', 'level' => 'debug'), 'console' => array('type' => 'console', 'bubble' => false, 'verbosity_levels' => array('VERBOSITY_VERBOSE' => 'INFO', 'VERBOSITY_VERY_VERBOSE' => 'DEBUG'), 'channels' => array('!doctrine')), 'console_very_verbose' => array('type' => 'console', 'bubble' => false, 'verbosity_levels' => array('VERBOSITY_VERBOSE' => 'NOTICE', 'VERBOSITY_VERY_VERBOSE' => 'NOTICE', 'VERBOSITY_DEBUG' => 'DEBUG'), 'channels' => array('doctrine')))))) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 45
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 39
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in Compiler.php line 117
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in ContainerBuilder.php line 614
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2638
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2411
at Kernel->boot() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2442
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 28
```

Answer (score 0):

I just have generated another symfony-project folder and moved the source-files in it. No idea what went wrong...